# How to play Video Using Url In Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

**I want play video Using Url but it shows dialog Message cannot play video.**

Here is my code.

```
VideoView video;
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(VideoActivity.this));
video.setVideoPath(path);
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

Comment: post the logcat. Have u made sure that th video is playable in Android default mediaplayer?

Comment: I am definitely sure this is not the code you use. The code you posted will cause NPE, because you do not initialize `video` anywhere. Please provide the full code and post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Uri is correctly typed? This is what caused the cannot play dialog message for me before